# node not found atfer installed with nvm

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, nvm, raspberry-pi4

I installed nvm using the script given on their github page and installed node 14.15.4 using `nvm install 14.15.4`. All went fine.

But when I try to use node, I get the following error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nvm list
   v14.15.4
default -> 14.15.4 (-> v14.15.4)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v14.15.4) (default)
stable -> 14.15 (-> v14.15.4) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.15.4)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.23.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.20.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.15.4

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nvm use 14.15.4
Now using node v14.15.4 (npm v)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node -v
bash: /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node: No such file or directory

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/
total 70728
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 72420168 Jan  4 11:10 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi       38 Jan  4 11:10 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi       38 Jan  4 11:10 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

As `ls` shows, the node file exists and is executable.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a symlink (A soft link is something like a shortcut in Windows. It is an indirect pointer to a file or directory. Unlike a hard link, a symbolic link can point to a file or a directory on a different filesystem or partition.)

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/bin/node // this will create a symlink to node
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" /usr/bin/npm //this will create a symlink to npm
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything, which sounds normal to me since it's looking for the node executable in `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin` and not in `/usr/bin`

Comment: I had a problem with Emacs and NVM using this solved the issue.